# Why am I getting an undefined for classlist that I don't call in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a tutorial React program I am working with that worked fine until I added a couple of buttons. They all give me the same error.

In the addClick, which does nothing at this point, gets the error before the console.log statement I have in the method. The only thing in the addClick is a console.log statement and I get the error before the console.log message is displayed. So the error happens from the click event, I assume.

[image]

The react code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { variables } from './Variables';

export class Department extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            departments: [],
            modalTitle: "",
            DepartmentName: "",
            DepartmentId: 0
        }
    }

    refreshLlist() {
        fetch(variables.API_URL + 'department')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ departments: data });
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.refreshLlist();
    }

    changeDepartmentName = (e) => {
        this.setState({ DepartmentName: e.target.value });
    }

    addClick() {
        console.log("in addClick");

    }

    editClick(dep) {
        this.setState({
            modalTitle: "Add Department",
            DepartmentId: dep.DepartmentId,
            DepartmentName: dep.DepartmentName
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {
            departments,
            modalTitle,
            DepartmentId,
            DepartmentName
        } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary m-2 float-end"
                    data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="exampleModal"
                    onClick={() => this.addClick()}>
                    Add Department
                </button>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                DepartmentId
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                DepartmentName
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Options
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {departments.map(dep =>
                            <tr key={dep.DepartmentId}>
                                <td>{dep.DepartmentId}</td>
                                <td>{dep.DepartmentName}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button"
                                        className="btn btn-light mr-1"
                                        data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="exampleModal"
                                        onClick={() => this.addClick()}>
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                            <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z" />
                                            <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z" />
                                        </svg>
                                    </button>

                                    <button type="button"
                                        className="btn btn-light mr-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="exampleModal"
                                        onClick={() => this.editClick(dep)}>
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                            <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z" />
                                        </svg>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>)
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-header">
                                <h5 className="modal-title">{modalTitle}</h5>
                                <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-body">
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <span className="input-group-text">DepartmentName</span>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" value={DepartmentName}
                                        onChange={this.changeDepartmentName} />
                                </div>
                                {DepartmentId === 0 ?
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-start">Create</button> :
                                    null
                                }

                                {DepartmentId !== 0 ?
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary float-start">Update</button> :
                                    null
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using bootstrap? Bootstrap uses non-react scripts to create the modal so that may be the problem. You could look at https://react-bootstrap.github.io

Comment: Well the tutorial I was using does use regular bootstrap so maybe that is the issue. But I would have assumed the person doing the tutorial would have the same issue. Will look at that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue. I had added react-bootstrap to try to get the modal to work and after making a few changes for the new modal, it worked.

But then I went back and saw that the author did have the same issue I was having and he had to make a change. He changed the code target in three places. I (and he, originally) had the target as "exampleModal". But you are looking for an ID and the ID is "exampleModal" but to point to the ID, you have to put a "#" first to denote ID. When I added the "#" to all the targets, it worked fine.

[image]

Here was where the error was happening in the modal.js file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your bootstrap html code with Reactstrap JSX's code
The error is from your bootstrap HTML code

Comment: Does the modal still work in React?